# Django unique together validation with request user

Tags: django

In Django, I need to validate `unique_together` the `author` and `title` fields.
The problem is that the `author` is the `request.user` so what is the best approach to validate the admin form?
I have this admin:

```
@admin.register(Document)
class DocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    exclude = ('author',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        """Save ``author`` as request user."""
        if getattr(obj, 'author', None) is None:
            obj.author = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

I can query inside the `save_model()` and filter both `author` and `title` but that doesn't really work well.
I also tried with a `forms.ModelForm` but I can't manage to get the `request.user` inside the `clean()` method.

This is my model:

```
class Document(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('title', 'author'),)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `author` field cannot be excluded from the admin. The solution is to hide the `author` using the `get_form` method. The `save_model` method is still useful if someone tries to change the hidden input value.

```
@admin.register(Document)
class DocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # exclude = ('author',)

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        """Make ``author`` field readonly on update."""
        return ['author'] if obj else []

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """Hide ``author`` selection default to request user on create."""
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if not obj:
            form.base_fields['author'].initial = request.user
            form.base_fields['author'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        return form

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        """Save ``author`` field as request user on create."""
        if getattr(obj, 'author') != request.user and not change:
            obj.author = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a unique_together constrain on your model

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('field_1', 'field_2')
```

Django will automatically do the validation for you, if it fails it will throw an IntegrityError (from django.db import IntegrityError)

Comment: So my question is: How to validate `unique_together` before the `IntegrityError`? The `author` field is not present in the form so Django won't validate against the `author` but it will throw an `IntegrityError`.

Comment: Can you add your models.py to the question

Comment: I already have `unique_together` in my model. It is like the one above with `unique_together = (author, title)`.

Comment: Are you adding this data from the Django Admin? If so, there should be an author field in your admin change form